# Javascript: Check screen width and remove HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, revolution-slider

I have a page that has 2 sliders; 1 for mobile devices & tablets (smaller than 500px screen width) and one for desktops (larger than 500px screen width). I am using CSS (display: block, display:none) attributes to display them accordingly, however, the browser is downloading the images of both sliders. I need a **Javascript code** that can;

- Identify the screen width
- Remove the desktop slider div by CSS class if the screen width is smaller or equal to 500px,
- Remove the mobile slider div by CSS class if the screen width is larger than 500px.

I **cannot use JQuery** because of some issues we have with the library and the way the website is designed (long story).

Here are the HTML elements;

```
<div class="show-desktop">
        [rev_slider alias="slider"][/rev_slider]
    </div>

    <div class="show-mobile">
        [rev_slider alias="slider-mobile"][/rev_slider]
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need two sliders?

Comment: [Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) does what you need, js-free

Comment: Hey , you need to try out some code yourself and then come back with a doubt or error. Even a little effort goes a long way when you're coding. Just try it please.

Comment: Hi, I did but it's pointless publishing my failed attempts. I'd rather ask a question in a concise manner

Comment: You will need to use something like `srcset`. It can specify different images for different screen resolutions. Check out the docs for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images And this approach doesn't require JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .show-mobile{
            display: none;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .show-desktop {
                display: none;
            }
            .show-mobile{
                display: block;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
        const vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(vw > 500){
            document.writeln('<div class="show-desktop">');
            document.writeln('\t[rev_slider alias="slider"][/rev_slider]');
        } else {
            document.writeln('<div class="show-mobile">');
            document.writeln('\t[rev_slider alias="slider-mobile"][/rev_slider]');
        }
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:-

Firstly we hided class `.show-mobile` using `display: none;`.

Next we created new CSS rule, exclusively for screens whose maximum width is 500px or less using `@media only screen and (max-width: 500px)`.

Finally, inside the rule, we hided class `.show-desktop` and displayed class `.show-mobile`.

JavaScript:-

Inside head section, we save view-port height and width in constants `vw` and `vh`, respectively.

Inside body section, we add `<div>` with appropriate class to the document according to the view-port's width.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am currently using that method, however, all the images are still being downloaded by the browser. I need to remove the html element so that the browser does not download the images of both sliders

Comment: Can you show some more of your code, where images are placed

Comment: I am sure there would be multiple images which need to be managed. Need to see your code for managing all of them.

Comment: So, here is one url - https://www.premierbet.com.gh/. If you use the inspect tool, you'll be able to find the images in the div called 'slotholder'. This is an automated class because the 'Revolution Slider' is a third party plugin. If you check my initial question above, the shortcode pulls in the third party slider code into the page. I created 2 sliders so that I am able to split the desktop from the mobile images. Revolution slider does offer mobile related options, but all the images are still downloaded by the browser, rendering these options useless.

Comment: You must use script to detect view-port size and write HTML accordingly. I am writing directly in the document. We can also take more modular approach and make load separate files for desktop and mobile and load content from them according to the view-port size. Whatever the case, use of script is inevitable if we want to load images according to view-port size.

Comment: The above snippet almost worked. The bahvior is exactly as needed, only the mobile pages are being downloaded on a screen width of less than 500px. The only issue is that the desktop images are not being loaded and some of the JS is being printed as text-> ** '); } else { document.writeln(' ** in desktop and **');
        } else {
            document.writeln(' ** on mobile. I think it's because the script is inserted before the shortcode

Comment: Check proper usage of quotes (' & ")